# Relation between $\exp(\mathbb{E}[X])$ and $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$

Tags: probability, expectation

I have a positive random variable $X$, can I prove any relation between $\exp(\mathbb{E}[X])$ and $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$. To elaborate, I don't have the PDF for $X$ but I do have its mean and from it I want to get $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$.

So, Can I prove any relation between both quantities? I believe there is no relation, but can I use $\exp(\mathbb{E}[X])$ to obtain a bound on $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X)]$? and what would be the conditions for such a bound to hold? also, how tight is this bound?

Comment: Jensen's inequality?

Comment: I know Jensen's inequality is a bound, but how tight is this bound?

Comment: You mean, as a general fact? There are random variables that do achieve the bound. A simple example is $X = a$ a.s., for some constant $a$.

Comment: So based on what I have, this is the best I can do, right?

Comment: There may be some refinements, but yes, I'd say so. You may want to read [e.g. this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/682/bounds-on-efx-in-terms-of-fex-other-than-jensens-inequality) (which gives insight as of the tightness of the bound).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality).  For a convex function $\exp$, we see that this implies $$\exp \operatorname{E}[X] \le \operatorname{E}[\exp X].$$  Conditions on when equality is attained are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I know Jensen's inequality is a bound, but how tight is this bound?

Comment: I believe I will not know with the information I have though.

Comment: @AhmedS. The tightness of the bound is dependent on the distribution of $X$ itself.  It can be made arbitrarily tight.

Comment: @AhmedS. two people have posted the same thing here...with such scant information on your random variable, you will not know. All we know is the mean and that $exp$ is a convex function.